# sonar query regarding configuration required in setting.xml

Tags: sonarqube

I have downloaded sonar and set it up 
Want to analyze a project - so made changes related to plugin in pom and set up the URL for the sonar install as well as the database properties that sonar is using ( mysql )

My question :
Why do we need to specify the URL in the maven_home\conf\settings.xml ?

```
<sonar.host.url>http://localhost:9000</sonar.host.url>
```

Why is this required ?
My understanding is when I run the mvn sonar:sonar from my dos prompt - sonar plugin ( defined in pom . xml ) is analyzing and then inserting the data into the database - using the db information provided in the settings

what is the usage of above URL ?
      Thanks,
      satish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all that is the default URL. If specify nothing at all the Sonar plugin will assume that there is a sonar instance running locally on port 9000.

You are quite correct when sonar completes it's analysis it uploads all results into the database directly using JDBC. The URL parameter is required because the Sonar plugin also uses the Sonar [REST API](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Web+Service+API) to retrieve information about your project when starting Sonar analysis.